# Number of Binary Tree with N Node and has same Postorder & Inorder Traversal

Tags: algorithm, recursion, data-structures, graph, tree

I Studying Cataln Number in few days. I Know Tree Traversal from WikiPedia.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal

But,

I confused with 1 Question. How many Binary Tree with N Node that has the same  Postorder & Inorder Traversal, We can construct?

Any Recurrence Relation or Sth Else would be appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about mathematics. Try the Math Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2):

A binary tree can have same Postoder and Inorder traversal if there is no right sub-tree anywhere that means every root either has left child or is the final node(leaf). That means this binary tree is just a list, hence total ways of arranging are n!.

Comment: Thanks so much. can you explain more detail? or add some example? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: if we change the question into.....How many Binary Tree with N Node that has the same Postorder & Inorder Traversal and with label 1 to N, We can construct? the answer is 1 tree? yes?

Comment: if you are talking about binary search tree than yes otherwise it is n!.

Comment: i'm sorry. i confused. for my first question in binary tree solution is N!? and the next question that has label 1 to N, is 1? am i right?

Comment: How does it matter what it has, if there are n distinct nodes answer is n!. If by binary tree you mean binary search tree(root>root.left) than there is only one way.